# How to make space between variable and operator in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, reformat

I'm using Mac & Windows, but the code reformat works differently on Mac and Windows.

On Mac

```
return response()->json([
    'access_token' => $jwtToken,
    'token_type'   => 'bearer',
    'expires_in'   => Auth::guard()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
]);
```

On Windows

```
return response()->json([
    'access_token' => $jwtToken,
    'token_type' => 'bearer',
    'expires_in' => Auth::guard()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
]);
```

I want to reformat the code like on Mac.

How can I adjust the code reformat rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Settings->Editor->Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces ->Array Initializer -> Align key-value pairs

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Also I checked Align consecutive assignments in Assignment statement !!